# How to make a discriminator for a real FSK signal?

Tags: phase, demodulation, fsk

I would like to create a discriminator of an FSK signal in order to demodulate it.

I only have the real part of the signal and it is centered in zero frequency (baseband)

My main problem is that I am not able to make the arctan of this signal because it is real. I am in a symetry issue using cos-1 or sin-1.

Do you have any idea how to transform it to a complex representation?

I was wondering if it was possible to use Hilbert transform. I heard of it but I don't know if it is suitable for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I only have the real part of the signal and it is centered in zero frequency (baseband)

Bad luck; with the real part of the signal you can't tell negative from positive frequencies.

Discarding the imaginary part discarded exactly that information. There's nothing you can do about that, the information is gone. Ignoring the imaginary part of a baseband signal literally ignores half of the signal content!

If your FSK was continuous-phase, you oversample sufficiently (i.e, especially not the MSK case), and the pulse shape applied before frequency-modulating is benign, and your SNR good enough, you might try to infer on whether you just saw a signal transition. You can't get the original bits that way, but you could maybe get the information of whether the last symbol is the same as the previous one. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. How is the imaginary part discarded? I shift a real signal with a real carrier to center it in zero. Maybe this is wrong?

Comment: well, how did you *shift*, exactly? Because when I shift a passband signal to zero, I end up with a *complex* baseband.

Comment: Multiply the real carrier with a sine and a cosine to create the complex baseband that would be needed as Marcus stated OR demodulate directly by multiplying the real signal with itself after a fixed delay at the carrier frequency that has a phase when centered at that carrier frequency of 90 degrees. (Or longer delays to have a higher gain but narrower bandwidth discriminator- some odd multiple of 90 degrees)

Comment: The RF card I intend to use outputs a real IF. In my model I shift it multipling it by a cosine. I understand that I have to shift it with an IQ carrier

Comment: My ADC has one channel

Comment: This is straying off into a separate question, which _you should ask separately_ (this is encouraged here).  The short story is that when you shift a signal down to _one_ channel of baseband you need to shift your signal such that the useful bandwidth of the signal is above DC, and such that any interference on either side of your signal isn't imaged _into_ your signal.

Comment: Fully agreeing with Tim. @dsp_curious if your ADC only has one channel, you simply cannot work in baseband. You need to work on a real IF, not on complex baseband.

Comment: Note that you can present the ADC with an IF of whatever frequency is necessary, then -- often with fairly low computational resources -- perform I/Q demodulation digitally, then downsample, then do the rest of your computation at the lower sample rate.

Comment: Multiplying the real signal with a delayed copy of itself requires no IQ- low pass filter the result and you have the demodulated FM signal. The delay should be 90 degrees at the carrier frequency